FCM unregistred errror
I am receiving unregistred error from fcm when I am using token to send notification
I created a fresh new token. Still same error presist, I have two projects, for one projects works fine.
{
"error": {
"code": 404,
"message": "Requested entity was not found.",
"status": "NOT_FOUND",
"details": [
{
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
"errorCode": "UNREGISTERED"
}
]
}
}
This is the error i got anybody faced same issue?
Hope some one replies
